# Related rates problem: Angles and actors

Tags: calculus, derivatives, contest-math

Suppose that a camera is fixed at $(0,0)$ in the coordinate plane (measured in feet). An actor starts at $(10,10)$ and moves down (negative y direction) at $1$ foot per second, and moves right (positive x direction) at $1$ foot per second, so that his position at time $t$ is $(10+t,10−t)$.

Let $θ$ be the angle between the positive x direction and the line of sight from the camera to the actor as a function of $t$. Find the rate of change of $θ$ as a function of time $t$.

$dθ/dt$ = ?

I tried and stuck with this: $dθ/dt$ = $\frac{\mathrm{cos}^2(θ)(-20)}{\mathrm{10+t}^2}$ because of angle of $θ$?

Comment: At time $t$, $\tan \theta = \cfrac{10-t}{10+t}$. Differentiate both sides.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to share your working? I do not know where you went wrong unless I see it.

Comment: $dθ/dt$ = $\frac{cos^2(θ) (-20)}{\mathrm{(10+t)}^2}$

Comment: The above answer not accepting. We need to find the value of $θ$

Comment: But $\tan \theta = \cfrac{10-t}{10+t} \implies \tan^2 \theta = \left(\cfrac{10-t}{10+t} \right)^2$ and $\tan^2\theta = \cfrac{1-\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}$. Can you find $\cos^2\theta$ in terms of $t$?

Comment: $\tan^2 \theta = \cfrac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta} = \left(\cfrac{10-t}{10+t} \right)^2$

$(1-\cos^2\theta) (10+t)^2 = (10-t)^2 \cos^2\theta$

$\cos^2\theta = \cfrac{(10+t)^2}{2 (t^2 + 100)}$

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm{sin}^2(θ)}{\mathrm{10-t}^2}\mathrm{10+t}^2=\mathrm{cos}^2(θ)$  I cannot get it in term of t. Bro, I am pretty dumb in math..

Comment: Thanks for that is a correct answer but how do you get it $\mathrm{cos}^2(θ)$?

Comment: See the steps in my comment. Expand and take $\cos^2\theta$ from LHS to RHS and then simplify. Note that $\sin^2\theta = 1 - \cos^2\theta$

Comment: Yes, I see but how did get rid of that $\mathrm{sin}^2(θ)$. That part I am not getting. You saw my solution above I end up t with $\mathrm{sin}^2(θ)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127673/discussion-between-math-lover-and-code-conundrum).